# Android source build system logs

Tags: android, android-source

I'm having some issues building the Android source. There aren't any clear errors returned on the terminal. How would I go about getting complete logs for the build to search through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `make showcommands`.
It gives you a more verbose output.

Comment: Does make showcommands run the build process and turn on verbosity, or does it just output logs after the fact? Sounds like the former,but want to make sure.

Comment: This answer is invalid, showcommands is obsolete, outdated, does  not work anymore since Android 6 kati, ninja.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by EyalBellisha, adding `showcommands` to make's goals is often useful. make normally echoes the exact commands that it runs (unless invoked with `-s`, `--silent`, or `--quiet`), but Android's build system hides this by prepending each command with `@`. Adding `showcommands` as a goal disables this, bringing the behavior back to make's standard behavior.

In some cases, building with parallel threads (i.e. running make with `-jN`, *N* > 1) can make it hard to correlate the echoed command with the command that failed the build. Temporarily dropping the `-j` option helps.

Once you have the offending command you can run it by hand to further debug the problems. There is a theoretic risk that it depends on environment variables set by make, making it hard to reproduce the exact execution environment, but I don't think Android's makefiles set up such environment variables so you're probably okay.

If you think make isn't evaluating rules properly and that this leads to errors (unlikely) then the `-d` and `--debug` options can be useful. The former turns on *all* debug output (massive wall of text for an Android build) and you may want to narrow it down with `--debug`.